# How to send bytes to AVR and use it on PWM

Tags: java, android, avr, pwm

I am trying to send integers from 0 to 255 to my Atmega8L AVR, and use that value as PWM and light up a LED for each pin (3 pins)...

I am doing this in Java (Android) to send data to my AVR via USART:

```
byte toSend[] = {(byte)intA, (byte)intB, (byte)intC};

bleService.writeMLDP(toSend); //sends data to AVR (byte[] or String, it's working fine)
```

In my AVR code I have the following:

```
int i = 0, filled_all = 0;
char bytes[3];

//ISR is called everytime data is received
ISR( USART_RXC_vect ) {
    bytes[i] = UDR; //UDR is the data received
    i++;
    if(i == 3) filled_all = 1;
    if(filled_all == 1) {
        OCR1A = bytes[0]; //sets 1st PWM
        OCR1B = bytes[1]; //sets 2nd PWM
        OCR2 = bytes[2];  //sets 3rd PWM
        i = 0;
        filled_all = 0;
    }
}
```

There is a lot of problems:

- All LEDs are starting on full-power (it's not inverted and I'm setting it to 0x00 at the start of my "main()";
- I have to send data twice to change the LEDs' power;
- 1st and 2nd pins are inverted (as if data is being sent like toSend[1] -> toSend[0] -> toSend[2]).

Comment: You should configure timers and pins, see datasheet for details ;) http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_Datasheet.pdf

Comment: Yes, there's a lot of code missing here to set up PWM with the timer(s).

Comment: What PWM mode are you trying to use?  What are your WGM bits set to?

Comment: I'm, currently, using Fast-PWM mode... Setting bits to WGM10, WGM12, WGM20 and WGM21